# How to fetch the common result of two queries?

Tags: mysql, sql

Say suppose I have two mysql queries which are something like this

```
if(!empty($company))
{
$q1="SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE company='$company'";
}
else
{
$q1="SELECT * FROM TABLE1;
}
$r1=mysqli_query($q1);
if(!empty($color))
{
$q2="SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE color='$color'";
}
else
{
$q2="SELECT * FROM TABLE1;
}
$r2=mysqli_query($q2);
```

While displaying result I tried comparing the pid(an auto_incrementing primary key) if

```
if($r1['pid]==$r2['pid])
{
/* display the contents */
}
```

But obviously this won't work cos if the pid is not equal then nothing is displayed and moreover both will not increment at the same pace, the next result of pid for r1 can be 23 where as in r2 it wil be only 12, this way nothing gets displayed.
The query which will have lesser results will make the filter work obviously, how can I set the smaller pid equal to the greater one within one cycle of the while loop which is displaying the result? If this can be done then also I guess my problem will be solved?

How can I achieve this?

I simply want to display the results that are common to both the queries.

**PS**: These queries are being generated dynamically so if any of $color or $company is empty then everything will be selected from the table.

**UPDATE** **Example**

r1 returns this

```
pid  company      color

1    acer          red
3    hp            red
5    logitech      red
6    compaq        red
7    microsoft     red
8    lenovo        red
```

AND r2 returns this

```
pid  company       color

5    logitech      red
6    compaq        red
7    microsoft     red
13   nvidia        red
```

Then from the above results we see that pid 5,6,7 exist in both r1 and r2, how to display all the columns with respect to these pids

Comment: There are a lot of syntax errors in your code with `"` and `'` signs.

Comment: Can you show an example of the data with your expected results?

Comment: Ok I will do that now

Comment: Not clear from the code in the question whether `$color` and `$company` have been properly escaped before being inserted into the queries. If they haven't, you need to do that, otherwise you're vulnerable to a SQL Injection hack.

Comment: Are your variables null or the blank string when "empty"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your application variables are blank when unassigned, you may combine the two conditions, *and* all of your application logic (testing for blank in app code), with this single, simple but elegant query:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE1
WHERE '$company' IN ('', company)
AND '$color' IN ('', color)
```

Note how by reversing the usual way you use `IN (...)`, you capture the ignore-if-blank logic with a minimum of code.

Comment: Yes this is way better because I tried to put my question in brief, I will be using atleast 7 variables and you have really cut short the code.

Answer (score 2):

Usually this is done with `INTERSECT`. MySQL however do not support `INTERSECT` so you have to use `JOIN`

`SELECT * FROM TABLE1 a WHERE company='$company' INNER JOIN
(SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE color='$color') b ON (a.pid = b.pid)`

Of course, if your case is so simple, you can just add the WHERE clauses

`SELECT * FROM TABLE1 a WHERE company='$company' AND color='$color'`

This is how you'd build the query dynamically, bases on whether company or color is selected:

```
$q1="SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE 1=1";
if(!empty($company))
{
$q1 .=" AND company='$company'";
}
if(!empty($color))
{
$q1 .=" AND color='$color'";
}

$r=mysqli_query($q1);
```

Comment: Honestly I did not think this far. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this query?

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE1 a
WHERE ('$company' = '' or company='$company') and
      ('$color' = '' or color='$color');
```